# How to change git from Chinese to English in mac

Tags: macos, git, bash

I remember I install git through `port install git-core`. And it show Chinese word as default like the followings:

```
# 位于分支 master
# 您的分支领先 'origin/master' 共 2 个提交。
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

and

```
# 位于分支 master
# 您的分支领先 'origin/master' 共 2 个提交。
#
# 尚未暂存以备提交的变更：
#   （使用 "git add <file>..." 更新要提交的内容）
#   （使用 "git checkout -- <file>..." 丢弃工作区的改动）
#
#   修改：      2.txt
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I work on mac os with Chinese language, and I want to know how can just change git's language back to English.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`

Add it to your .bashrc or .zshrc file

Answer (score 10):

if you use fish shell

`~/.config/fish/config.fish`

```
set -x LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
set -x LC_CTYPE en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 7):

You may try to set `LANG` environment variable to `en_US.UTF-8` by adding the following line to your your `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

It helped me to switch my Git language to English on macOS Mojave.

Answer (score 2):

If you use iTerm2.

add `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` to `.bash_profile` file

then, `source ~/.bash_profile`

But it doesn't work when you restart the iTerm2

then fix:
add `source ~/.bash_profile` to `.zshrc` file

Comment: After trying multiple things, _only this answer_ fixed my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To make it persistent in Fish:

```
set --universal LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

For bash on my mac this seems to fix the problem
`echo "alias git='LANG=en_GB git'" >> ~/.bashrc`